# Count method to total up the records with a boolean field set to a particular state. RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, count

I’m trying to use the `.count` method to total up the records with a boolean field set to a particular state.

For example, a blog’s Post table has a field named `posted_at` which has a null value when the post has not yet been posted (draft only) and contains a timestamp when the post has been posted.

Running `@posts.count` returns the total number of posts, as expected

Running `@post.posted?` returns the `posted_at` field’s state, as expected

However running `@posts.posted.count` fails with a `method_missing` error
I have tried `posted?.count` and get the same.

It seems that ActiveRecord was smart enough to figure out that when targetting one record, `posted?` should check the state of the `posted_at` field without a `posted?` method being defined in the model. Is it also smart enough to know what we are trying to do when adding a .count method into the mix or do we need to define it as a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic method created by ActiveRecord to do this, but you could use a `scope` for this purpose, by adding this to your `Post` model:

```
scope :posted, -> { where.not(posted_at: nil) }
```

Then, you will be able to do this anywhere:

```
@posts.posted.count
```

Comment: Thank you @haradwaith, that was exactly what I was after.